# How to get cell address by clicking a datapoint on an Excel scatter plot?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a three column table. Two of the columns provide the xy values used to generate the scatter plot. The third columns contains hyperlinks. So each row contains a x value, y value, and hyperlink(each link is unique). How do I get the cell address of the corresponding hyperlink when I click on a data point on the excel scatter plot?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is to have your column of hyperlinks in a named range. Once they are then it is straight forward enough to reference them from the chart.

Not entirely sure what you are asking but this will pop up with a message box of the value in the cell next to the Y value / cell when the data point is clicked on.

One way of doing this is to have your column of hyperlinks in a named range. Once they are then it is straight forward enough to reference them from the chart.

If you have the chart on a separate Chart worksheet then you can use the following code (embedded on the Chart Worksheet module):

```
Private Sub Chart_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Dim lngElementID As Long
    Dim lngArg1 As Long
    Dim lngArg2 As Long

    'Only catch Left-Clicks
    If Button = xlPrimaryButton Then
        With ActiveChart
            'Get the coordinates of what has been clicked
            call .GetChartElement(x, y, lngElementID, lngArg1, lngArg2)

            If lngElementID = xlSeries Then
                If lngArg2 > 0 Then
                    'Range containing the messages to be displayed
                    Set varRange = Worksheets("Sheet1").[ChartURLs]

                    Call MsgBox(CStr(varRange(lngArg2, 1)))
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If the chart is just embedded on a normal Worksheet, there is a lot more to it as we need to catch the Chart events using WithEvents. Add the following code to a new Class module:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents chartEvents As Chart

Private m_rngPopupMsgs As Range

Private Sub chartEvents_MouseUp(ByVal Button As Long, ByVal Shift As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
    Dim lngElementID As Long
    Dim lngArg1 As Long
    Dim lngArg2 As Long
    Dim varRange As Variant

    'Only catch Left-Clicks
    If Button = xlPrimaryButton Then
        With ActiveChart
            'Get the coordinates of what has been clicked
            .GetChartElement x, y, lngElementID, lngArg1, lngArg2

            If lngElementID = xlSeries Then
                If lngArg2 > 0 Then

                    If Not (m_rngPopupMsgs Is Nothing) Then
                        Set varRange = m_rngPopupMsgs
                        Call MsgBox(CStr(varRange(lngArg2, 1)))
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Public Property Get PopupMsgs() As Range
    Set PopupMsgs = m_rngPopupMsgs
End Property

Public Property Set PopupMsgs(rngPopupMsgs As Range)
    Set m_rngPopupMsgs = rngPopupMsgs
End Property

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_rngPopupMsgs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Then add a new Code module and add the following code.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_objChtEvents As New clsChartEvents

Public Sub SelectChart(ByRef wks As Worksheet, ByRef rngPopupMsgs As Range)
    Dim objChart As Chart

    If wks.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then
        Set m_objChtEvents = New clsChartEvents

        Set objChart = wks.ChartObjects(1).Chart
        Set m_objChtEvents.chartEvents = objChart

        Set m_objChtEvents.PopupMsgs = rngPopupMsgs
    End If
End Sub
```

The in the Worksheet module of the worksheet containing your chart, you need to add a call to the SelectChart() procedure from the Worksheet_Activate event (or any other event of your liking) as follows replacing "ChartURLs" with the name of your range:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Call SelectChart(Me, Range("ChartURLs"))
End Sub
```

Hopefully this is the sort of thing you are looking for, if not then it should at least be a good start.